# PL/SQL/Функция не возвращает несколько строк

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Я хотел выбрать 10 высокооплачиваемых сотрудников из таблицы "сотрудники", но функция вернула только 1 строку. Как получить несколько строк в этом случае?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sal
RETURN Varchar2

IS cursor c_emp is (select first_name, last_name from (select first_name, last_name, row_number() 
over(order by salary desc) as ranking from employees) where ranking <= 10);
v_first employees.first_name%type;
v_last employees.last_name%type;

begin
open c_emp;
fetch c_emp into v_first, v_last;
close c_emp;
return v_first || ' ' || v_last;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
  THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('Error');
     when others then dbms_output.put_line('Other Error');
END;
  
select f_sal from dual;
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы функция вернула несколько строк, она должна быть табличной функцией, то есть возвращать табличный тип данных и вызываться в клаузе `FROM`.

Попробуйте такой воспроизводимый пример:

```
create or replace type emprow force is object (fname varchar2 (32), lname varchar2 (32))
/
create or replace type emptab  is table of emprow
/
create or replace function gettopemp return emptab is
    cursor empcur is
        select emprow (first_name, last_name) 
        from hr.employees
        order by salary desc
        fetch first 3 rows only;
    ret emptab;
begin
    open empcur;
    fetch empcur bulk collect into ret;
    close empcur;
    return ret;
end;      
/
```

Запрос с табличной функцией и его результат:

```
select * 
from table (gettopemp ());

FNAME                            LNAME                           
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
Steven                           King                            
Neena                            Kochhar                         
Lex                              De Haan
```